# Question on $1-$form integration and exactness.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let $\omega = -\frac{4z}{(x^2+1)^2}dx+ \frac{2y}{y^2+1}dy+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dz,$ and let $\eta = -\frac{4xz}{(x^2+1)^2}dx + \frac{2y}{y^2+1}dy+\frac{2}{x^2+1}dz$. Evaluate the line integrals over the straight line segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$ and determine which is exact.

**Solution Attempt**

For a straight line segment, we have

$$\gamma:[0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^3$$

via

$$t \mapsto (t,t,t).$$

And we know

$$\int_\gamma \omega = \int_{[0,1]} \gamma^* \omega.$$

So for

$$\int_\gamma \omega$$

I get

$$\int_0^1 -\frac{4t}{(t^2+1)^2}dt+2\int_0^1 \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt=-1+2\ln(2).$$

For $\eta$ I get

$$\int_\gamma \eta = \int_0^1 - \frac{4t^2}{(t^2+1)^2}dt+\int_0^1 \frac{2t}{t^2+1}dt+2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^2+1}dt=1+\ln(2).$$

And for which is exact, I claim $\eta$ is exact with potential function

$$f(x,y,z)=\ln(y^2+1)+\frac{2z}{x^2+1}.$$

How do you generally prove something is not exact? Since showing exactness relies on existence of a potential function. So is $\omega$ not exact? I tried so hard but could not find a potential function whatsoever.

**Added:** I think I figured out to show $\omega$ isn’t exact. We’d need the partial of the first term wrt $z$ to be the same as the last term partial w respect to $x$ but they aren’t equal thus it’s not exact. I.e., If $\omega_1 = -\frac{4z}{(x^2+1)^2}$, and $\omega_3 = \frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ Then in order to have closed we need

$$\frac{\partial \omega_1}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial \omega_3}{\partial x}$$

But this does not hold.

Comment: Your calculations look correct. Have you checked if $\omega$ is closed? If not it will not be exact. If yes: on which domain is it defined? Figure that out and apply the Poincare lemma.

Comment: Ahhhh since $\Bbb{R}^3$ is contractible every closed $1-$form on it is exact? By Poincaré Lemma. @KurtG.

Comment: Those question marks are irritating. Have you found something about the Poincare lemma that makes you unsure? Back to $\omega$. Is it closed? Just saw your **Added:** will respond soon.

Comment: @KurtG. what question marks? And I just added to my post that I found $\omega$ to not be closed thus it cannot be exact.

Comment: The question mark in "Ahhhh since R3
 is contractible every closed 1−
form on it is exact?" Now back to $\omega\,.$ Your remark in **Added** gives a reader the impression that only one term of $d\omega$ needs to be checked. I hope this is not your understanding.

Comment: @KurtG. wait, I thought that for it to be closed we must have $\frac{\partial \omega_j}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial \omega_i}{\partial x^j}$ for all $i,j$ so if one pair doesnt satisfy the equality then its not closed? Sorry, I am new to this stuff and my professor doesnt explain well.

Comment: I see Ted has viewed the post. Hi Ted!

Comment: True. For all $i,j\,.$ This post could stay of low quality as it is or easily become a fruitful piece in the biggest solution manual of the world (aka MSE) if you showed all steps to your readers.

Comment: To be frank, @KurtG. I always work out an exercise myself and only come here when really stuck or wanna be certain im doing the right thing.

Comment: You are free to view MSE as a service provider for your problems when you got stuck. My view of it is that sometimes we should give something back to the community.

Comment: @KurtG. yeah definitely I’ve answered tons here and a bunch more on my Quora account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $$
\omega=a\,dx+b\,dy+c\,dz
$$ to be closed we have to check if $d\omega\equiv 0\,.$ This means the three
parentheses in
$$
d\omega=(\partial_yc-\partial_zb)\,dy\wedge dz+(\partial_xc-\partial_za)\,dx\wedge dz+(\partial_xb-\partial_ya)\,dx\wedge dy
$$
must vanish. In your case
\begin{align}
a &=  -\frac{4z}{(x^2+1)^2}\,,&b&=\frac{2y}{y^2+1}&c&=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\,.
\end{align}
So the first and last parenthesis vanish, but not the second:
\begin{align}
(\partial_yc-\partial_zb)&=(\partial_xb-\partial_ya)=0\,,\\[2mm]
(\partial_xc-\partial_za)&=-\frac{2(-3+x^2)}{(x^2+1)^2}\,.
\end{align}
Since $\omega$ is not closed it cannot be exact.